# how to reinitiate a default field value every time the content edition is loaded?

Tags: 8, entities

i have a field that , if opt-in, send notifications.
I would like that when editing the content , the value is always reinitiated to opt-out, sitll leaving the possibility for the editor to opt-in again

this code below does it but then it is not possible to save an opt-in nomore

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function mymod_entity_load(array $entities, $entity_type_id)    {

  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    if ($entity instanceof NodeInterface) {
      if($entity->bundle()=='evenement'){
         $entity->field_notif=0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x)

```
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

    /*
     * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
     */
    function mymod_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      if($form_id == 'node_evenement_edit_form'){ // target a specific form
        $form['field_notif']['widget']['#default_value'] = 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: when saving ,i do enter in the  condiition if($form_id == "node_evenement_edit_form") but the field value modification is not seen when clicking then to edit

Comment: @Matoeil forgot that you need `['widget']`

Comment: that do it now :), we are not supposed to say the T word but thanks

Comment: it does not seem to work for "text long" field : $form['field_message_a_notifier']['widget']['#default_value'] = "Un message optionnel.";

Comment: it is for text (long) format $form['field_message_a_notifier']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value']